# Adding JButton to JPanel by pressing JButton problem

Tags: java

I'm creating a program for table reservations for practice. I came across the next problem: When I click on button "Create new table", a Button should be added on centerPanel, but it does not appear there.

Here's the code

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

public class CreateNewFloorV2 extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    JFrame frame=new JFrame("Create new table");
    BorderLayout borderLayout=new BorderLayout();

    JPanel centerPanel=new JPanel();
    SpringLayout centerPanelLayout=new SpringLayout();

    JPanel bottomPanel=new JPanel();
    GridLayout bottomPanelLayout=new GridLayout(1,2);
    JButton btn1=new JButton("Create new table");
    JButton btn2=new JButton("Delete table");

    //Constructor
    public CreateNewFloorV2() {
        frame.setSize(600, 400);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);

        //Create layout
        frame.setLayout(borderLayout);
        frame.getContentPane().add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        centerPanel.setLayout(centerPanelLayout);
        frame.getContentPane().add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        bottomPanel.setLayout(bottomPanelLayout);
        bottomPanel.add(btn1);
        bottomPanel.add(btn2);
        btn1.addActionListener(this);
        btn2.addActionListener(this);

        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    //ActionListener
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource()==btn1) {
            JButton newTable=new JButton("Table X");
            centerPanel.add(newTable);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CreateNewFloorV2 newFloor=new CreateNewFloorV2();
    }
}
```

I've tried putting

```
JButton newTable=new JButton("Table X");
centerPanel.add(newTable);
```

into constructor CreateNewFloorV2() and then it does appear. But I don't know why it doesn't appear when I click on button btn1 and how should I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Simply adding the component won't suffice - You have to tell the windowing toolkit to redraw the frame. Try using something like this:

```
if(e.getSource()==btn1) {
    JButton newTable=new JButton("Table X");
    centerPanel.add(newTable);
    centerPanel.invalidate();
    centerPanel.repaint();
}
```

Also see https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html